# Unable to read UTF-16 file

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, utf-16

I am trying to read a file with an encoding of UTF-16 in a Spark dataframe. However, when I display the result of my dataframe, I get unwanted special characters in my result-set.

I have tried the following - using UTF-16BE:

```
df = spark.read.format('text').option("encoding", 'UTF-16BE').option("charset", 'UTF-16').option('delimiter', "\|").option('header', 'false').option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").load(filepath)
```

And have tried the following using UTF-16LE:

```
df = spark.read.format('text').option("encoding", 'UTF-16LE').option("charset", 'UTF-16').option('delimiter', "\|").option('header', 'false').option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"").load(filepath)
```

Both attempts return the unwanted special characters.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: `text` format does not support encoding option. Use `csv` instead. See available options here : [text](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#text-scala.collection.Seq-), [csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-java.lang.String...-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use [`csv`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-java.lang.String...-) instead of [`text`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#text-java.lang.String-), as `text` format doesn't support the options you're trying to use. Try :

```
df = spark.read.format("csv")\
    .option("encoding", "UTF-16")\
    .option('sep', "|")\
    .option("escape", "\"")\
    .load(filepath)
```

Note that the default value for option `header` is false so no need to specify it, same for `quote`. Also, there is no option `charset`, you only need the `encoding` option.

You can find all available options for each data source here: [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html)